# laravel is giving error on custom controller used in routes

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, routes, laravel-routing

I have a simple in routes/web.php file

```
Route::get(Config::get('constants.ADMIN_PATH') . '/categories', 'AdminControllers\AdminPagesController@index');
```

I have made a folder AdminControllers and inside that there is a controller named AdminPagesController but i am getting error as

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\AdminControllers\AdminPagesController does not exist
```

Whereas i looked into the same folder and class exist. Here is my class code

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

```
class AdminPagesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function index () {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you namespace to

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminControllers;
```

Laravel will resolve controllers based on your name spacing, not on your directory structure.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the namespace correctly, change it to:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminControllers; // <------- correct this namespace

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminPagesController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function index () {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @HabibJutt - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!

Comment: No fight bro, its all depends upon the OP... :D

Comment: Just a shady move to ask for the accept when someone else answered first

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to nest your controllers deeper into the **

> App\Http\Controllers

---

** directory, use the specific class name relative to the

> App\Http\Controllers

root namespace.

> namespace App\Http\Controllers\AdminControllers;

---